# UTF8String method in iphone

Tags: iphone

If I have

```
NSString *myString          = @"string for data1"    
const char *utfMyString     = [myString UTF8String];
NSLog(@"length of my myString is %d",[myString length]);
NSLog(@"length of my utfMyString is %lu",strlen(utfMyString));
```

I looked up the definition of method UTF8String which returns a null terminated at the end for the receiver. Therefore, i think length of ***utfMyString*** should be **17**.

Unfortunately, ***utfMyString*** still is length of ***16***.
Please correct me about this issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen()` doesn't include the terminating null character in its length count.

Comment: so what if i wanna print out the length that also includes the null character.what should I do